# How do I ignore the spaces?

Tags: java

To make telephone numbers easier to remember, some companies use letters to show their telephone number. Ex, using letters, the telephone number 438-5626 can be shown as get loan.
Write a program that prompts the user to enter telephone number expressed in letters and outputs the corresponding telephone number in digits. if user enters more than seven letters, then process only first seven letters. Also output the -(hyphen) after the third digit. Allow the user to use both uppercase and lowercase letters as well as spaces between words.

I am not sure how do I make it so that it will ignore the spaces.
Also I am new to programming, please advise, thanks!

I typed: i love java programming as input, but it doesn't ignore the spaces.
it is okay if i enter java programming. with first word being 4 letters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assignment1Q3{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String hpletters;
    char hpdigits;

    System.out.print("\nEnter phone number in letters only: ");

    hpletters = input.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        hpdigits = hpletters.charAt(i);
        if(i==3)
        System.out.print("-");
        if(hpdigits >= 'A' && hpdigits <= 'Z' || hpdigits >= 'a' && hpdigits <= 'z')
        {
            switch(hpdigits)
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                case 'B':
                case 'b':
                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                    System.out.print("2");
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'd':
                case 'E':
                case 'e':
                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                    System.out.print("3");
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'g':
                case 'H':
                case 'h':
                case 'I':
                case 'i':
                    System.out.print("4");
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'j':
                case 'K':
                case 'k':
                case 'L':
                case 'l':
                    System.out.print("5");
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'm':
                case 'N':
                case 'n':
                case 'O':
                case 'o':
                    System.out.print("6");
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'p':
                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                case 'R':
                case 'r':
                case 'S':
                case 's':
                    System.out.print("7");
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 't':
                case 'U':
                case 'u':
                case 'V':
                case 'v':
                    System.out.print("8");
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'w':
                case 'X':
                case 'x':
                case 'Y':
                case 'y':
                case 'Z':
                case 'z':
                    System.out.print("9");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , it will help you to post question accurately

Answer (score 0):

You've *almost* got it, except:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

You'll want to loop over the entire input string, not just a hard-coded 8 characters (which it won't be if your input doesn't contain exactly one space, which is the case you seem to have hard-coded for). Otherwise you'll run into problems if your input string isn't exactly 8 characters (you can test your code to discover these problems on your own).

And:

```
if(i==3)
    System.out.print("-");
```

There, `i` represents the number of input characters that have been processed, *not* the number of digits that have been printed, and these two things will not be equal if the input contains spaces. So you'll want to find a way to print a hyphen after you've *outputted* three digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove white space like below,

```
String str = "i love java programming";
str = str.replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

To just ignore spaces, you can replace them.

However, you should step back first and boil down your code to your three main problems:

1. You have user input, so you should validate it.
2. You have characters, which should be ignored (spaces) or be handled like others (lower and upper).
3. You need to transform letters to a number with a hyphen.

When you organize your code like that, you get smaller problems to solve. It's also obvious what the code does without further documentation in comments. And on top of that, you might be able to put aside some code, because you "ignored" some cases.

```
public class Assignment1Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nEnter phone number in letters only: ");
        String hpletters = input.nextLine();

        if (isValid(hpletters)) {
            String normalizedHpletters = normalize(hpletters);
            String transformedNumber = transformToNumberWithLength(normalizedHpletters, 7);
            System.out.println("The phone number is: " + transformedNumber);
        }
    }

    private static String transformToNumberWithLength(String hpletters, int length) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char hpletter = hpletters.charAt(i);
            if (i == 3) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
            if (hpletter >= 'A' && hpletter <= 'Z') {
                switch (hpletter) {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'C':
                        sb.append("2");
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'F':
                        sb.append("3");
                        break;
                    case 'G':
                    case 'H':
                    case 'I':
                        sb.append("4");
                        break;
                    case 'J':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'L':
                        sb.append("5");
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'O':
                        sb.append("6");
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'S':
                        sb.append("7");
                        break;
                    case 'T':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'V':
                        sb.append("8");
                        break;
                    case 'W':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'Z':
                        sb.append("9");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String normalize(String hpletters) {
        return hpletters
                .toUpperCase()          // only upper case
                .replaceAll(" ", "");   // remove spaces
    }

    private static boolean isValid(String input) {
        if (!(input.replace(" ", "").length() > 6)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter at least 7 characters (ignoring spaces).");
            return false;
        }

        if (!input.matches("[A-Za-z ]+")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter letters a-z only.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```